# Google Ad Conversion Snippet: Obj-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, sdk, google-ads-api

I'm following Google's [steps](https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/ios/#incorporate_the_sdk) for adding the Google SDK to my iOS app so I can track installs from Google ads. I've completed all the steps. However, the little snippet of Objective-C that goes into the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, thats getting an error message because my app is in Swift. How do I translate it to Swift?

```
[ACTAutomatedUsageTracker enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID:@"IDString"];

[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:@"IDString" label:@"String" value:@"0.00" isRepeatable:NO];

[ACTAutomatedUsageTracker disableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID:MY_CONVERSION_ID];
```

Do I need to add something to the Bridge-Header? The guide I followed for the Facebook SDK had me create a header file with this code:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h 

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

#endif /* Bridging_Header_h */
```

Picture of Google SDK imported into the Project Navigator.

[image]

So my two questions are:

1. Does anyone know how to translate the above snippet into Swift?
2. Do I need to add code to my bridge header and, if so, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to add code to my bridge header and, if so, what?

Absolutely. In order to access Objective-C code in Swift, you would need to define the import in a header file named "MyProjectHere-Bridging-Header.h". Next, make sure that in build settings, under Swift Compiler -  Code Generation, you have "Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name" set to your new header file.

Header code will look something like this:

```
#ifndef AppName_Bridging_Header_h
#define AppName_Bridging_Header_h

#import "ACTReporter.h"
#import "GoogleConversionPing.h"
#import "DCTReporter.h"

#endif /* AppName_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Once that's done, just go into the new header file and do a #import statement for the header files in the Google framework, and you should be able to use it in your App Delegate just as if it were Swift:

i.e.

```
let useageTraker: ACTAutomatedUsageTracker?

usageTracker.enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID("\(ID)")
```

Full Swift code for appDelegate:

```
ACTAutomatedUsageTracker.enableAutomatedUsageReportingWithConversionID("0123456789")

ACTConversionReporter.reportWithConversionID("0123456789", label: "XXXXXX", value: "0.00", isRepeatable: false)
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Doing that now. Any idea how to make the appDelegate.swift file accept the objective-C lines?

Comment: Hi Dave, you can't use two different languages in the same file - you have to do the import statement in the separate header, then write it in the correct language syntax for the file you are using. If your app delegate is in Swift, the code in it must be in Swift.

Edit: Clarity and Grammar